Как на Windows работать с websocket django channels?
я хочю интегрировать websocketы в свой джанго проект, при пропытке установить django channels[daphne]
пишет что нехватает модуля 'fcntl ' , но этого модуля и нет на винде, он есть только на маке или убунту наверное.
вся документация только про daphne, а все видеоуроки походу устарели, так как из них ничего не работает СОВСЕМ.
подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?
как сделать вебсокеты в джанго если у меня винда?
